# Building a function of a random variable dynamically in python

Tags: python, random, scipy

I have some random variables using `scipy.stats` as follows:

```
import scipy.stats as st
x1 = st.uniform()
x2 = st.uniform()
```

Now I would like make another random variable based on previous random variables and make some calculations like `var` for the new random variable. Assume that I want the new random variable to be something like `max(2, x1) + x2`. How can I define this dynamically?

Comment: Just to be clear: you want to simulate drawing a sample of the random variables **max(2,x1)+x2**, and then calculate the variance of this sample?

Comment: I don't think creating functions of random variables is that easy. Your example can be calculated analytically but I doubt that any package is able to provide a general solution. You can create two random arrays and reach a conclusion based on a simulation though.

Comment: @Bill I didn't understand what you mean by variance of the sample. But what I mean is that for example, for `x1` I can say `x1.var()` to get the variance. I want something similar for the new random variable.

Answer (score 1):

My old answer appears below:

(I was prompted to look at this question again when answers that refer to SO documentation were edited to remove those references. I think this is a better answer anyway.)

First of all, as far as I'm aware, there's no general way of getting a nice closed-form expression for the variance of a non-linear function of two or more variables. Probably most mortals resort to some kind of Monte Carlo strategy for approximating quantities such as this.

Here's some code that generates a plot that does this for this specific situation. It's adaptable to many others.

Generate two pseudorandom samples from the unit uniform random variable, then calculate the pseudorandom random variable `Y` as a function of the elements of these samples.

```
>>> import scipy.stats as stats
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> import numpy as np
>>> X1 = stats.uniform.rvs(0,1, 5000)
>>> X2 = stats.uniform.rvs(0,1, 5000)
>>> Y = [max(2,x1)+x2 for (x1,x2) in zip(X1,X2)]
```

Now, in hopes of identifying the density function of this function, plot its histogram.

```
>>> plt.hist(Y)
(array([ 501.,  526.,  490.,  481.,  513.,  488.,  525.,  490.,  521.,  465.]), array([ 2.00012599,  2.10007992,  2.20003386,  2.2999878 ,  2.39994173,
        2.49989567,  2.59984961,  2.69980354,  2.79975748,  2.89971141,
        2.99966535]), <a list of 10 Patch objects>)
>>> plt.show()
```

We're quite lucky because it's easily identified. Here it is.

[image: histogram of the function]

It's a uniform whose support is the closed interval [2,3]. We can again use scipy, this time to obtain its variance. Other moments are available; see the documentation.

```
>>> stats.uniform.stats(2,1, moments='v')
array(0.08333333333333333)
```

**None of this was really necessary though, was it?**

As a U(0,1) random variable X1 never exceeds 1. Therefore, max(X1, 2) must be 2. Then 2+X2 must be U(2,3). This random variable has the same scale as X2; only its location has changed. Therefore its variance must be the same, and the variance of a U(0,1) is 0.0833333.

**Edit the 'next' day:**

Having just learned (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/46383333/131187) that sympy now supports random variables I was eager to try it out on this problem.

```
>>> from sympy.stats import Uniform, Variance
>>> from sympy import symbols, Integral
>>> X1 = Uniform('X1', 0, 1)
>>> X2 = Uniform('X2', 0, 1)
```

Alas, as the author of that other answer notes, it seems unable to handle expressions involving `max`.

```
>>> Variance(max(2, X1) + X2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sympy-1.0.1.dev0-py3.4.egg\sympy\core\relational.py", line 195, in __nonzero__
    raise TypeError("cannot determine truth value of Relational")
TypeError: cannot determine truth value of Relational
```

But in the case of this problem that's not essential. It's easily eliminated. We have, which yields the exact value of the integral for the variance.

```
>>> Variance(2 + X2)
Variance(X2 + 2)
>>> Variance(2 + X2).evaluate_integral()
1/12
```

'Old answer' begins here:

Not directly, I think. However, this approach might be of use to you.

Assume to begin with that you know either the pdf or the cdf of the function of the random variables of interest. Then you can use rv_continuous in scipy.stats to calculate the variance and other moments of that function.

Obviously the 'fun' begins here. Usually you would attempt to define the cdf. For any given value of the random variable this is the probability that an expression such as the one you gave is not more than the given value. Thus determining the cdf reduces to solving a (an infinite) collection of inequalities in two variables. Of course there is often a strong pattern that greatly reduces the complexity and difficulty of performing this task.

Comment: I tried it by defining cdf but I get the following error: `object has no attribute '_parse_args_stats'`

Comment: The subclass of `rv_continuous` needs to define `_cdf`, not `cdf`.

Comment: @MehdiJafarniaJahromi: I dunno. Can we see your code?

Comment: @Bill I fixed my mistake. I should have called the super `__init__` function to make my code work.

Answer (score 0):

In OpenTURNS, the use [Symbolic functions](https://openturns.github.io/openturns/latest/user_manual/_generated/openturns.SymbolicFunction.html?highlight=symbolicfunction)  allow you a larger variety of manipulations.

In your case, x1 and x2 would represent independant distributions

```
import openturns as ot
x1 = ot.Uniform() 
x2 = ot.Uniform()
```

Thus, the composed distribution whose marginals are x1 and x2 would be:

```
dist = ot.ComposedDistribution([x1, x2], ot.IndependentCopula(2))
dist.setDescription(["x1", "x2"])  # labels 

# note the use of "IndependentCopula of dimension 2" as second argument
```

If you want a sample of size = 5

```
sample = dist.getSample(5)
print(sample)
>>>     [ x1        x2        ]
0 : [ -0.752141 -0.897212 ]
1 : [  0.850966  0.857914 ]
2 : [ -0.340213 -0.344882 ]
3 : [ -0.166526  0.458643 ]
4 : [  0.378453 -0.908958 ]
```

As said earlier, you can define a model based on (x1, x2) as symbolic function. In your example:  y = max(2, x1) + x2

```
model = ot.SymbolicFunction(["x1", "x2"], ["max(2, x1) + x2"])
```

that you can apply to `model(sample)`

```
    [ y0      ]
0 : [ 1.10279 ]
1 : [ 2.85791 ]
2 : [ 1.65512 ]
3 : [ 2.45864 ]
4 : [ 1.09104 ]
```

But your model can be multidimentional. For example:

```
model = ot.SymbolicFunction(["x1", "x2"], ["x1^2+x2", "x2^2+x1"])
```

applied to sample will give a 2-dimension sample

```
>>>    [ y0         y1      ]
0   -0.331496   0.05284813
1   1.582057    1.586982
2   -0.2291374  -0.2212693
3   0.4863741   0.04382738
4   -0.7657314  1.204657
```

This is very interesting when creating more advanced models. In this last case, plotting an output of size 10,000 `out = model(dist.getSample(10000))` gives

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.scatter(out.getMarginal(0),out.getMarginal(1), s=0.5)
```

[image]