# Defining two random variables that depend on a single condition

Tags: probability, sympy

In sympy, how can I define two random variables, X and Y, that depend on a common condition? For example, how do I solve a problem such as the following:

- We throw a dice. If it falls on 1, then X=1 and Y=0. If it falls on 2, then X=0 and Y=1. Otherwise, X=Y=0. What is the covariance of X,Y?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If X and Y are functions of some Z, then create Z and define X, Y through it. `Piecewise` helps with this:

```
from sympy.stats import *
Z = Die("Z", 6)
X = Piecewise((1, Eq(Z, 1)), (0, True))
Y = Piecewise((1, Eq(Z, 2)), (0, True))
print(covariance(X, Y))  # -1/36
```

---

Aside: If Y is a function of X, then create X first and then define Y in terms of it.

```
from sympy.stats import Bernoulli, covariance
X = Bernoulli("X", 1/6)
Y = 1 - X
print(covariance(X, Y))
```

Returns -0.138888888888889.

Comment: I updated the answer; SymPy is now better at these calculations, so the workaround with interpolating_poly is not needed.